# Unable to connect to Google Cloud SQL with node App Engine and TypeOrm

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, typeorm

I am using typeorm and with ;extra.socketPath; in the `ormconfig` file. I'm getting:

```
Error : Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/[project:region:instance] at
PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
```

The `ormConfig.json` file contains the following JSON content:

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "extra": {
    "socketPath": "/cloudsql/[project:region:instance]"
  },
  "username": "root",
  "password": "xxxx",
  "database": "yyy",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": [
    "build/entity/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Original poster found a fix in an identical post on [TypeOrm’s github page](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3263#issuecomment-447628958). They got it to work by using the Cloud SQL IP as their host and changing their firewall to allow it.

Answer (score -1):

You will also need to specify the host as

> /cloudsql/[project:region:instance]

unless specified it will connect to 127.0.0.1